# add list of objects in lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I using lucene 4.7.0  to store data. I want to add list of objects in a lucene document. For e.g.

```
Class A{
    private List<B> listOfB;
    private String  field1;
}

Class B {
    private String name;
    private String  date;
}
```

I want to add field1  which is straight forward  but how can I store  "listofB" in lucene document of A ?

Thanks
Samby

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question and I don't see a response to - **will we able reconstruct our class a object?** so answering here .

Basically , you have to employ serialization and deserialization to store and retrieve a complex object as a Lucene Document field .

I followed [this article](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Storing-a-serialized-object-td561410.html)

I am using Lucene 6.6. and below are sample code as part of Indexing and Searching ,

```
Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new TextField("content", startBean.getIndexable(), Field.Store.NO));

        ByteArrayOutputStream serData=new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
        ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(serData);

        try { 
            out.writeObject(startBean); 
        } finally  { 
            out.close(); 
            serData.close(); 
        } 

        FieldType filedType = new FieldType();
        filedType.setStored(true);
        filedType.setTokenized(false);

        doc.add(new Field("storedcontent",serData.toByteArray(),filedType));

        writer.addDocument(doc);
```

Basically, I have a POJO of type - `StartBean` with instance as `startBean` . It has a String field that I am using as a lucene indexed field and storing full `startBean` as `byte[]` in Lucene index.

Then at search time, if a hit is found ,

I do - `Document doc = searcher.doc(hit.doc);` then call below method - `StartBean startBean = getStartBean(doc);` to reconstruct my object.

```
private StartBean getStartBean(Document document) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException{

        StartBean startBean = null;

        BytesRef binaryValue = document.getBinaryValue("storedcontent");

        if(null != binaryValue){
            System.out.println("binaryValue is non null ");

            byte[] bytes = binaryValue.bytes;

            ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(new 
                    ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)); 
                            try { 
                                startBean = (StartBean) in.readObject(); 
                            } finally  { 
                                    in.close(); 
                            } 
        }

        return startBean;

    }
```

You have to make sure that your parent object and nested objects are either `Serializable` or marked `transient` ( Basic serialization - deserialization rules ).

Let me know for any clarification on any code part.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do so, and some time it depends on your business.

We had the same situation, what we did in this case as the following:

**First**

we determine the fields that should be add to index and its type. the type here to determine the field value, weather it single value or list and etc.

**Second**

if the field was an list of objects like your case, we simply loop through that list and add each field in that object as separate(sometimes), or combine that object fields value as one String value then add it as a.

**For Example**:

```
for (B b : list) {
    luceneDoc.add(new TextField(KEY, b.getName(), STORE_TYPE));
    luceneDoc.add(new TextField(KEY, b.getDate(), STORE_TYPE));
}
```

OR

```
for (B b : list) {
    luceneDoc.add(new TextField(KEY, getBfieldsValue(b), STORE_TYPE));//getBfieldsValue(b) should return a one String value from all B fields.
}
```

**NOTE:** *I used TextField as example, you should use the field type depend on your business.*

Comment: Thanks Salah, but while retrieving through query , will we able reconstruct our class a object?

Comment: I didn't get the first question??, and `org.apache.lucene.index.MultiFields` is not `indexableField`.